# Allure report 2.6.0: Unable to delete directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\xxx\ui-selenide\build\allure-results after the second tests run

Tags: teamcity, allure

Following error happens after the second launch of autotests.

There is java.exe process with "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6e1072cc098a9044\ui-selenide\build\allure-results" handle name presents in the the Resource Monitor.

I've tried to kill this process but the teamcity build works unstable.

After each reboot the Teamcity agent tests work properly (the trends graph is displayed correctly).

```
[13:49:13]Step 3/4: Launch Test Suite (Command Line) (1s)
    [13:49:13][Step 3/4] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1941821006218141349.cmd
    [13:49:13][Step 3/4] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6e1072cc098a9044\ui-selenide
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] :clean FAILED
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] 
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] 
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] * What went wrong:
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] Execution failed for task ':clean'.
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] > Unable to delete directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\6e1072cc098a9044\ui-selenide\build\allure-results
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] 
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] * Try:
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] 
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] BUILD FAILED in 1s
    [13:49:15][Step 3/4] Process exited with code 1
```

Allure report 2.6.0 
Teamcity 2017.2.4
Windows 7
Selenide 4.10.01

Can you please help to fix this issue ?